# How to search for specific field inside the @message field in Opensearch

Tags: querydsl, opensearch

I am trying to filter all the records that have the dSId field as blank under the msg or the @message section. But, unable to find any specific query that is able to do this.

How would one be able to search for any sub-strings inside the "msg" or the "@message" sections for the following record:

```
{
  "_index": "dummy-value",
  "_id": "1234",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "level": 12,
    "time": "2023-08-22T03:48:31.692Z",
    "pid": 12,
    "hostname": "<value>",
    "reqId": "req-27h",
    "teamId": 8789,
    "msg": "This message:8789, wfId: b1550f15, aId: , dSId: , status: failed",
    "@id": "4356546",
    "@timestamp": "2023-08-22T03:48:31.693Z",
    "@message": "{\"level\":12,\"time\":\"2023-08-22T03:48:31.692Z\",\"pid\":12,\"hostname\":\"<value>\",\"reqId\":\"req-27h\",\"teamId\":8789,\"msg\":\"This msg: 8789, wId: b1550f15, accountId: , dSId: , status: failed\"}",
    "@owner": "54654",
    "@log_group": "logger",
    "@log_stream": "logger"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-08-22T03:48:31.693Z"
    ],
    "time": [
      "2023-08-22T03:48:31.692Z"
    ]
  }
```

I have tried to search on  _source.msg.dSId using exists filter but it seems not working and the results fetch those records which have a value for the dSId fields in both the sections.

Also used the regexp based filter but that too is not returning any results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "dSId": "[a-z][A-Z]*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you're indexing your data? what's the process, do you have an ingest pipeline already?

Comment: I am not too sure about the indexing operation of the data but there is an ingest pipeline. Since I have access only to the opensearch dashboards, building some monitors from them for notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an ingest pipeline, you should leverage the [`key_value` processor](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.0/data-prepper/pipelines/configuration/processors/key-value/) in order to split the `message` field.

If you add the following into your pipeline, you should be able to query the `dsId` field easily:

```
  {
    "key_value": {
      "source": "msg",
      "field_split_characters": ",",
      "value_split_characters": ":",
      "delete_key_regex": "\\s",
      "delete_value_regex": "\\s"
    }
  }
```

Then you can query the `dsId` field for the empty string `""` like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "dSId": ""
      }
   }
}
```

If you really need to find blank `dSId` fields without properly parsing your data (but that's probably a bad idea), the query below would do the trick, i.e. it will find all documents with a `msg` field containing a blank `dSId`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "msg.keyword": ".*dSId:[ ]+,.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @val. Isn't there a way to search for this field from the current output in Opensearch using any of the functions? To modify the ingestion pipeline, it would take quite some time hence looking for options to get the desired result without taking that path.

Comment: Not sure why it'd take that long to run a PUT on your ingest pipeline, but I've updated my answer with a regexp query that should do the trick.